# CDI: ProxyObject ClassCastException when inject DAO

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, cdi, websphere-8

I am trying to instantiate DAO classes using CDI 1.0 in Websphere 8.0. In my Workspace I have an EJB class located in an EJB project which calls a DAO class located in a DAO project. I followed [this example](http://blog.caelum.com.br/acessando-multiplos-bancos-de-dados-com-jpa-e-cdi/) (in Portuguese, sorry) which used a Producer method. These are the classes:

The DAO class (in the DAO project):

```
public class NaturezaDAO extends BaseDAO<NaturezaORM> {

    @Inject
    public NaturezaDAO(EntityManager em) throws DAOException {
        super(NaturezaORM.class, em);
    }

    // ...

}
```

The Producer class (in the DAO project):

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

/**
 * code extracted from 
 * http://blog.caelum.com.br/acessando-multiplos-bancos-de-dados-com-jpa-e-cdi/
 */
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    @RequestScoped
    @Produces
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        System.err.println("\t\tEntityManagerProducer.createEntityManager()");
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        System.err.println("\t\tEntityManagerProducer.closeEntityManager()");
        if (manager.isOpen()) {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

}
```

The EJB class (in the EJB project):

```
@Stateless
public class NaturezaServiceBean extends BaseSB implements NaturezaService {

    @Inject
    private NaturezaDAO naturezaDAO;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public List<NaturezaORM> listNaturezasPropositura() throws BusinessException, EntityNotFoundException {
        try {
            return this.naturezaDAO.listByTipoAtivoDeputado(
                TipoNaturezaEnum.ME, SimNaoEnum.S, SimNaoEnum.S);
        } catch (ObjectNotFoundDAOException e) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(e);
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            throw new BusinessException(e);
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

When I initialize the server, apparently there is no problem. However, when I call the EJB method, I got this Exception:

```
[22/04/15 14:39:26:838 BRT] 0000001a InjectInjecti E   CWOWB0102E: Ocorreu um erro do JCDI: org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_0 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
[22/04/15 14:39:26:839 BRT] 0000001a BusinessExcep E   CNTR0019E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "listNaturezasPropositura". Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_0 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_0 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
```

I am not sure if it makes any difference, but in both projects there are `beans.xml` files in the `META-INF` directory.

Any suggestion about what is missing here?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: The error mentions this call: exception during invocation of method "listNaturezasPropositura". Can you share the code you're using to call and this method implementatino?

Comment: @MarcosMaia, I edited the EJB class. Now it is showing the `listNaturezasPropositura()` method.